# Downloading files from the OECD website works on Windows, but not in Linux

Tags: r, download

I'm trying to download ZIP (and other) files from the OECD website using `download.file` and other functions in R. I am able to do so under Windows, but not in Linux (did not try MacOS, as I don't have a Mac machine).

**EDIT**
I am able to download other file types like TXT and DOC from the same page and they all work fine (except for ZIP and SAS files, where I get `403 Forbidden`) using `download.file()` without any special treatment.

I have searched SO for solutions, but none of these helped. Below are different attempts, they work on Windows, but not on Linux. I have tried these in Arch Linux and Fedora 39.

**Attempt 1**

```
> options(HTTPUserAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0")
> download.file(url = "https://www.oecd.org/pisa/pisaproducts/intcogn_v4.zip", destfile = "/tmp/intcogn_v4.zip")
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6048  100  6048    0     0  92656      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 93046
```

The above downloads the `intcogn_v4.zip` file, but it is just 5.9KB when saved on disk, while the original file is 8.49MB. I can't open the downloaded file using any archive software. I tried to open it using a text editor just to see that it is actually an HTML file.

**Attempt 2**

```
> library(curl)
> curl_download(url = "https://www.oecd.org/pisa/pisaproducts/intcogn_v4.zip", destfile = "/tmp/intcogn_v4.zip", quiet = TRUE, mode = "wb", handle = new_handle())
Error in curl_download(url = "https://www.oecd.org/pisa/pisaproducts/intcogn_v4.zip",  : 
  HTTP error 403.
```

**Attempt 3**

```
> require(httr)
> headers = c(`user-agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.61 Safari/537.36')
> httr::GET(url = "https://www.oecd.org/pisa/pisaproducts/intcogn_v4.zip", httr::add_headers(.headers=headers))
Response [https://www.oecd.org/pisa/pisaproducts/intcogn_v4.zip]
  Date: 2023-11-24 13:52
  Status: 403
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 6.54 kB
```

In the second and the third attempt I see status 403 (forbidden) in the output. I have installed `libcurl` in both Fedora and Arch Linux. I have checked the `libcurl` capabilities in R and everything seems fine:

```
> capabilities("libcurl")
libcurl 
   TRUE
```

Am I doing something wrong or there is an issue with this specific website?